# What can we conclude about $a_{-1}$ and $a_{-n}$ for $n>1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $0<|z|<\epsilon$, $\epsilon >0$ given by a convergent Laurent series $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$ Given also that $lim_{z\to 0} |f(z)|=\infty$.

What can we conclude about $a_{-1}$ and $a_{-n}$ for $n>1$.

I want to know how to deal with such type of questions (not too good with complex analysis, and this question kinda scared me) as I had to leave it in an exam I recently attempted.

Thanks!

Comment: CSIR-UGC NET2016 december problem!

Comment: yes. So correct option was 2.

Comment: @vidyarthi did you give that exam too?

Comment: yes, and I missed my own logic in the exam to choose the wrong answer!

Comment: I am not too good with analysis and complex. What was your part? Can you tell me some answers in chat?

Comment: did you get the answer key by some source?

Comment: naah. there is one on aglasem but its very very wrong. I am looking for solutions online

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50406/discussion-between-vidyarthi-and-departed).

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is holomorphic in the punctured plane, and $\lim_\limits{z\to0}|f(z)|=\infty$ therefore, by [Casorati-Weierstraß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) theorem, the point 0 cannot be an essential singularity. Hence, $a_n$ is zero for some $n\geq N\in \mathbb{N} $ for $N>1$, typically, $a_{-1}\neq0$.

Comment: Your logic is no good here. $e^{1/z}$ is holomorphic on all of $\Bbb C-\{0\}$. It's the limit condition that rules out an essential singularity. Also, you mean to say that for some $N$, $a_n=0$ for all $n\ge N$. Your quantifiers are all mixed up.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks, modified the answer.